# Using xml-rs xml::reader::Error to return a custom error

Tags: error-handling, rust, xml-rs

I'm using `xml-rs` to do some xml parsing and there are some special cases where I want to issue a custom `xml::reader::Error`. This error struct is implemented as:

```
pub struct Error {
    pos: TextPosition,
    kind: ErrorKind,
}
```

`pos` and `kind` attributes are private, so I cannot instantiate a `Error` manually, and there is no `new()` method or something like that.

What I have is this `From` implementation:

```
impl<'a, P, M> From<(&'a P, M)> for Error where P: Position, M: Into<Cow<'static, str>> {
    fn from(orig: (&'a P, M)) -> Self {
        Error{
            pos: orig.0.position(),
            kind: ErrorKind::Syntax(orig.1.into())
        }
    }
}
```

I can use this to instantiate a custom error, I need a `P` which implies a type which implements `xml::common::Position` trait and a `M` which is a `Into<Cow<'static, str>>`.

For, `P`, I think I can use `xml::reader::EventReader` since it implements `xml::common::Position`. But I'm not sure how to obtain `Into<Cow<'static, str>>`.

I tried doing something like this:

```
(event_reader, "custom error").into()
```

But it doesn't work, I think because `"custom error"` cannot be converted to `Into<Cow<'static, str>>` or something like that.

The error message I receive is this one:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `xml::reader::Error: std::convert::From<(xml::EventReader<std::io::BufReader<&[u8]>>, &str)>` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:234:78
    |
234 |                                     _ => return Err((event_reader, "custom error").into()),
    |                                                                                    ^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<(xml::EventReader<std::io::BufReader<&[u8]>>, &str)>` is not implemented for `xml::reader::Error`
    |
    = help: the following implementations were found:
              <xml::reader::Error as std::convert::From<(&'a P, M)>>
              <xml::reader::Error as std::convert::From<xml::util::CharReadError>>
              <xml::reader::Error as std::convert::From<std::io::Error>>
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::Into<xml::reader::Error>` for `(xml::EventReader<std::io::BufReader<&[u8]>>, &str)`
```

As can be seen, from the error, Rust is unable to convert my `(event_reader, "custom error")` tuple to the available `xml::reader::Error as std::convert::From<(&'a P, M)>` implementation.

That's what I want to know why and how to fix.

Comment: You don't own `xml::Error`, so creating custom instances of that error doesn't sound right. You are actually advised to roll your own error type.

Comment: Also, please include the compiler's error messages on those code snippets.

Comment: Hello @E_net4 I added the error message in the main question message. Also, I know I can create my own error type, for now this is the workaround I'm using to progress with the code.. But for this case, I want to use `xml::reader::Error` since I see this error as a xml syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was not adding the `&` to the event_reader. Adding it fixed the issue and now the `From` implementation is called and I can instantiate an `xml::reader::Error`:

```
(&event_reader, "custom error").into()
```

Comment: While technically this compiles and works, I don't think this is a **good** idea. If the library intended you to put whatever custom error kinds you wanted, they would have exposed a more obvious way of doing so. This seems much closer to abusing accidentally public functionality.